# OpenGL window not responding when performing computation on GPU

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, cuda, glut

It is a CUDA Code which performs ray tracing. The OpenGL window is used to display the output of the ray tracing performed. Since, the RayTrace is quite slow, I am not particularly concerned about OpenGL performace etc.

But when the ray-tracing (startRayTrace()) is called, the OpenGL window just goes to "Not Responding" State, and displays the output once the ray tracing is finished.

I can't figure out how to prevent it going into the not-respond state. When it goes in not respond state, I cannot minimize the window etc. but the rendered image is still shown as it is.

```
void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float image[768][1024][3] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 768; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j) {
            int idx = (767 - i) * 1024 + j;
            image[i][j][0] = host_c[idx].x;
            image[i][j][1] = host_c[idx].y;
            image[i][j][2] = host_c[idx].z;
        }
    }

    glRasterPos2i(-1, -1);
    glDrawPixels(1024, 768, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void winResize(int w, int h) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport( (w>1024)?((w-1024)/2):(0), (h>768)?((h-768)/2):(0), w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void startRayTrace() {
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cam_offset, &cam_offset_global, sizeof(double), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    init <<< 1, 1 >>> ();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    char title[35];

    //rayTrace <<<48, 16 >>> ();
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
        rayTrace <<< 1, 32 >>> ();      //Overcome Watchdog timer on Windows without disabling TDR
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        sprintf(title, "Ray Tracing | Rendering %.2f%%...", ((i + 1) / 24.f) * 100);
        glutSetWindowTitle(title);
    }

    copyToHost <<< 1, 1 >>> (dev_c);
    cudaMemcpy(host_c, dev_c, WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(vector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

void keyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'd') {
        cam_offset_global += 10;
    }
    if (key == 'a') {
        cam_offset_global -= 10;
    }
}

void keyUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'd' || key == 'a') {
        startRayTrace();
    }
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    cudaMalloc(&dev_c, WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(vector));

    //OpenGL Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutCreateWindow("Ray Tracing | Rendering 0%...");

    //Ray Tracing
    startRayTrace();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    const GLubyte* ren = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    printf("\n\n\n OpenGL Renderer : %s \n\n", ren);

    //Register Callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(winResize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
    glutMainLoop();

    delete[] host_c;
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    return 0;
}
```

Once the ray-trace is done, the host_c[] stores the image data, which I use to display the output on glWindow. The glutPostRedisplay() is supposed to re-render the output once ray trace finishes and host_c[] is updated, but the glWindow hangs until the ray-tracing finishes.

Comment: The only thing I can tell is that openGL runs on Nvidia GPU, which is currently being used for ray-tracing. I am not sure if that's the problem, and if that's the case, I don't know any workaround either.

Comment: Currently, this is expected behavior when using the same GPU for compute operations (e.g. kernel calls) and graphics operations (e.g. OpenGL).  When a kernel is running, the GPU will not service graphics tasks.

Comment: You are launching 1 block with 1 thread for the whole scene, and then calls `cudaDeviceSynchronize();`, which will block until kernel completion. I believe what you are experiencing is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

GLUT is not going to read further events, while it's being right inside an event hand.er You're calling `startRayTrace` right from the keyboard callback. However `startRayTrace` doesn't just start the raytrace, it also waits for completion. And because of that, GLUT will be stuck until the raytrace finishes.

CUDA kernels are executed asynchronously. To get note of when the kernel finishes, add a `cudaEvent` right after the kernel in the CUDA stream. Then register a GLUT `idle` callback function. In that function, poll if the event did complete, and when the event did complete, issue a `glutPostRedisplay`.

Do not `cudaSync…` inside the keyboard function, because that will stall.